# Dynamically change email recipient in webform based on dropdown list

Tags: 7, webforms

I have a reservation form for booking restaurants. All restaurants are added dynamically into the webform using [Webform Views Select](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_views_select).

When the user selects resturant1, that restaurant should get an email of the reservation. Restaurants are nodes and, when I add them, I add an email field too, so this is in the database. But still I can't figure out how to make this work.

I know I need to use rules but I'm not really sure how to set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the view you are using creates an option list of key|value pairs of the form **nid|Restaurant name**. For this answer, I will call your select element **restaurant**.

1. Install and activate the [Webform node value](http://drupal.org/project/webform_node_value) module. <strike>This is a new module, and you will have to apply [this patch](http://drupal.org/node/1967000). (If you are not familiar with patches have a look at [Applying Patches](http://drupal.org/patch/apply).)</strike>
2. Edit your webform, and under *Form components* create a "Hidden" webform element called **send_to_email**.
3. Under *E-mails* add Component value: **send_to_email** as the *to address*.
4. Under *Form settings* go to the bottom and open the *Set Value From A Node* group.

   - The *Path To Node* is **From webform field**.
   - Since the key returned is nid, set the *Path Alias Prefix* to **node/** so the nodes can be found using node/nid as the path.
   - The *Webform Source Field* is **restaurant** (your select element).
   - If the field containing the email address of the restaurant is $node->field_email, set the *Node Source Field* to **field_email**.
   - The *Webform Target Field* is **send_to_email**.

Comment: In meanwhile i tried another approach with Entityforms but im gonna try this answer too.

Comment: This answer is amazing. Been trying to configure something like this for weeks.

Answer (score 0):

As you setup the outgoing mails with the webform module, you can select another webform field value as the source for the recipient of the outgoing email.

As you have select options, the value of the field needs to be the email and the title the name of the restaurant.

Comment: The select list is being created dynamically. The email address cannot be used as a key value because keys are restricted to letters, numbers and underscores. Therefore the email address will have to be determined after the selection has been made, based on the selected key value. There are also security considerations with placing plain text email addresses in the page code.